# Get the distro from a distutils setup call

Tags: python, unit-testing, installation, distutils

I want to unit test some Python extensions. To achieve this I'm running `setup()` in a script:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import os

DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def call_setup():
    module1 = Extension('callbacks',
        sources = [os.path.join(DIR, 'callbacks.c')])

    setup(
        script_name = 'setup.py',
        script_args = ['build'],
        name = 'PackageName',
        ext_modules = [module1])
```

To avoid leaving junk in the test directory I want to cleanup the build after the tests run. I'd like to run `distutils.command.clean.clean()` in the unittest `tearDown()`. How do I get the `dist` object for the distro that must be passed as an argument to `clean()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your call to `setup()` should [return a `Distribution` instance.](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Distribution)

> See the `setup()` function for a list of keyword arguments accepted by the `Distribution` constructor. `setup()` creates a Distribution instance.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is right. Alas, `clean.run()` doesn't [do anything](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/py3k/Lib/distutils/command/clean.py), so I'll just remove (or ignore) the directory myself.